# Pre-check checkboxes in rails form based on database and then update database after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am developing my first rails app and have run into an issue. Basically in my user model I have a column called likes which is by default set to a string of zeroes and each position in that string is supposed to represent a specific checkbox. The database is sqllite3 if that makes a difference. I have my check boxes set up as follows

```
//The string in question is stored in
<%= current_user.likes %>

<%= form_tag do %>
<%= check_box_tag(:like_acoustic) %>
<%= label_tag(:like_acoustic, "Acoustic") %>
//More checkboxes
<%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
```

What I am looking to do is pre check any checkboxes (as the page loads) if the corresponding value in the string is 1 and leave them unchecked if it is 0. So "100" would lead to the first checkbox being checked and the second two not. Then when the submit button is clicked I would like to generate a new string based on what the check boxes currently signify (1 for checked, 0 for unchecked) and update current_user.likes with this new value. I am just learning rails so I really appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason that you're storing the likes in this way?

Comment: I am using the likes to match users and the algorithm I am using compares strings character by character so it seemed to make sense to store them as strings of 1s and 0s

Comment: This strikes me as a recipe for bugs down the road. If you could store the likes in columns named `like_acoustic`, etc it will be a lot easier to build with Rails conventions, it'll be more maintainable for other decks, and it'll be human readable in other formats.

Comment: That makes sense, so kind of like a column for each genre and treat them as booleans? I'm pretty new to rails and database type stuff but I just assumed it would be slower to compare individual database columns than it would be to character comparisons of strings. (I don't have much basis for that)

Comment: Any performance advantage you might gain from string comparison would be negated by database inefficiencies. I recommend using Rails conventions instead - a separate column for each kind of like may seem like a lot of overhead, but being explicit also will make it easier to manage your data in the future and understand what's going on in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string `current_user.likes` into an array of numbers, then iterate over them:

```
<% current_user.likes.split("").each do |like| %>
  <%= "Label" %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'likes[]', !like.to_i.zero?, !like.to_i.zero? %>
<% end %>
```

You can then retrieve the string after submitting with:

```
likes.join("")
```

Comment: So that generates all of the checkboxes but they are all filled in by default (the default string is 0) and how would I go about labeling said checkboxes?

Comment: Updated - you might need to convert the 0s and 1s to boolean true/false

Comment: So if I wanted to give each checkbox a unique name such as genre1, genre2 and so on would I create a string of all the names delimited by something or could I just use a bunch of if statements to change the value of label?

Comment: You can use `each_with_index` like so: `<% current_user.likes.split("").each_with_index do |like,index| %>
  <%= "genre_#{index}" %>`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have it working with the custom names now, still trying to get the likes.join("") to work but hopefully I can figure it out

Comment: Okay, I am sorry to be annoying again but I still can't get it to submit and rejoin. Would the change to booleans have made this more difficult?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a compelling architectural reason to do so (e.g. you're working with a legacy database) I would strongly advise against setting up your database like this. Any performance advantage you may gain from character comparison will be negated tenfold by inefficiencies in querying the database.

Instead, since you're using Rails, do it the Rails way.

Include a column in your database for each kind of like. Then when you write your form you can take advantage of all Rails' form helpers without having to parse ones and zeros.

```
<%= check_box_tag(:like_acoustic) %>
<%= label_tag(:like_acoustic, "Acoustic") %>
```

You'll also get the advantage of being able to easily query the database for your likes:

```
User.where(like_acoustic: true)
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but what would be the storage space overhead in creating all the new columns? The strings representing all the genres are about 114 digits long so I'd be looking at that many new columns in my database

Comment: 114 columns would be a lot but I doubt the storage would add up to much. More likely it would make the UI unwieldy. One other option that would still be Rails-y is to use PostgreSQL's hstore format. Then you could have a single column called likes and store the genres and bookies values as a hash in the likes column. That would still be efficient to query, and would be easier to manage in your ui.